# Live app crash on UIImage imageNamed:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I'm having some weird issues with our app, it crashes when using some `UIImage`.
I get the image with `[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"]` from the image asset. 
But on some device it returns `nil` which crash my app, but It should not be `nil`.
I've already checked and its running on the main thread, there is enough memory left (although it was running low).

***The image is PDF as single vector image in the image assets, this should create the correct sizes of the images.***

Can any one give me any pointers on how to resolve this issue?

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  CoreFoundation                 0x1844d7108 CFDataGetBytePtr + 36
1  Foundation                     0x18545a848 bytesInEncoding + 204
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1844e88d4 -[__NSCFString UTF8String] + 80
3  CoreUI                         0x18d6827c0 -[CUIStructuredThemeStore _canGetRenditionWithKey:isFPO:lookForSubstitutions:] + 780
4  CoreUI                         0x18d6a5614 -[CUICatalog _resolvedRenditionKeyFromThemeRef:withBaseKey:scaleFactor:deviceIdiom:deviceSubtype:sizeClassHorizontal:sizeClassVertical:memoryClass:graphicsClass:graphicsFallBackOrder:] + 1484
5  CoreUI                         0x18d6a4784 -[CUICatalog namedLookupWithName:scaleFactor:deviceIdiom:deviceSubtype:sizeClassHorizontal:sizeClassVertical:] + 148
6  UIKit                          0x18a3df338 __98-[_UIAssetManager imageNamed:scale:idiom:subtype:cachingOptions:sizeClassPair:attachCatalogImage:]_block_invoke + 424
7  UIKit                          0x18a3df0d8 -[_UIAssetManager imageNamed:scale:idiom:subtype:cachingOptions:sizeClassPair:attachCatalogImage:] + 212
8  UIKit                          0x18a4f1698 -[UIImageAsset imageWithTraitCollection:] + 404
9  UIKit                          0x18a3df7c0 -[_UIAssetManager imageNamed:withTrait:] + 276
10 UIKit                          0x189e7277c +[UIImage imageNamed:inBundle:compatibleWithTraitCollection:] + 220
11 UIKit                          0x189ccb47c +[UIImage imageNamed:] + 124
12 Speakap                        0x1000bef50 -[LoadingView commonInit] (LoadingView.m:74)
13 Speakap                        0x1000beabc -[LoadingView initWithFrame:] (LoadingView.m:28)
14 Speakap                        0x1001348dc -[BaseTableViewController viewDidLoad] (BaseTableViewController.m:32)
15 Speakap                        0x1001570d4 -[BaseMessageViewController viewDidLoad] (BaseMessageViewController.m:66)
16 Speakap                        0x10014aa34 -[MessageViewController viewDidLoad] (MessageViewController.m:37)
17 UIKit                          0x189b8c098 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 996
18 UIKit                          0x189ba4350 -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 132
19 UIKit                          0x189d3dfb4 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 1052
20 UIKit                          0x189c4a190 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 688
21 UIKit                          0x189c49e6c -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 60
22 UIKit                          0x189c49dd4 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 208
23 UIKit                          0x189b877ac -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 644
24 QuartzCore                     0x189386b58 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
25 QuartzCore                     0x189381764 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 292
26 QuartzCore                     0x189381624 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32
27 QuartzCore                     0x189380cc0 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 252
28 QuartzCore                     0x189380a08 CA::Transaction::commit() + 512
29 UIKit                          0x189b7d9d8 _afterCACommitHandler + 180
30 CoreFoundation                 0x1845afbd0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
31 CoreFoundation                 0x1845ad974 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
32 CoreFoundation                 0x1845adda4 __CFRunLoopRun + 928
33 CoreFoundation                 0x1844dcca0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
34 GraphicsServices               0x18f718088 GSEventRunModal + 180
35 UIKit                          0x189bf4ffc UIApplicationMain + 204
36 Speakap                        0x100162b24 main (main.m:14)
37 libdyld.dylib                  0x19990a8b8 start + 4
```

Comment: Have you try to add the extension of your image. "imageName.png" for example ? Without the @2x/@3x

Comment: @ejanowski I'm pretty sure that's never necessary, even when not using images.xcassets.

Comment: @Kevin indeed, it is not necessary IF the image is png type. If it is jpg, you have to specify the extension.

Comment: @ejanowski the image is a PDF import as a single vector.

Comment: how you are creating images from single vector & using them in application?

Comment: Are you attempting to load many many images, for example a series of images in a row that make up this animation? Because you might just be running out of memory because you loaded too many images into memory.

Comment: I think nor the image or memory pressure is the problem. It seems for me you call an object (observer) which has been deallocated (released). CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION

Comment: Please post the code that uses `CFDataGetBytePtr`...

Comment: @l'L'l there is no code using `CFDataGetBytePtr` in my project.

Comment: Are you using any `CFDataRef` or `CGImage` functions at all? The crash at `CFDataGetBytePtr` indicates that the method that calls it isn't getting what it expects (and why you get nil). If you're not using any of those functions then it's likely ui problem (eg. storyboard with bounds set to dimensions smaller than your image), although without seeing another crash report i can only speculate.

Comment: Nope, just `imageNamed:`

Comment: A few more questions: Is the crash completely random, or is it after a certain number of times you load the image? Does it crash on the same devices each time, same version of iOS, same orientation (portrait, landscape)?

Comment: @l'L'l it is random, almost always on a iPhone 6 or 6+ with iOS 9. I've not seen the crash on any 32bit device only on 64 bit. I'm only us the portrait orientation.

Comment: If you happen to have another crash log it might be worth comparing the two to see if the stacks follow the same pattern — I forgot to ask you if it's the same `PDF` each time (I'll presume it's also random). Maybe try setting dimensions for your image (check ui layout where it's placed for bounds >= image) or save the PDF differently as a test. Beyond that I'd say it's a bug and let Apple know about it.

Comment: @rckoenes Did you solve this? Having the exact same issue in an app live in app store right now. **Only** devices between iOS 9.0 and 9.2.1 (including both) crash. Our crash logs say that most of the crashes are related to UIImage.imageNamed:, but not exclusively. When I build my app directly on an iOS 9.2.1 device, it doesn't crash. But if I download the same build from AppStore **or TestFlight** it crashes for almost every second/third UIImage.imageNamed it comes over. Impossible to debug!

Comment: @Sti no I never did solve this. I could never replicate the issue (neither in an ApptSore build or development build). Also the issue was been dropping in the number of crashes they we decided it no longer worth the time.

Answer (score 3):

I've experienced some "trouble" in memory management using `[UIImage imageNamed:@""]` within low memory context.

As the documentation says:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed:

> **Discussion**
>
> This method looks in the system caches for an image object with the specified name and returns that object if it exists. **If a matching image object is not already in the cache**, this method locates and loads the image data from disk or asset catalog, and then returns the resulting object. In **iOS 9 and later, this method is thread safe**.

I don't know on which OS the crash happens, but it can be an idea.

Other point, does it still happens if your replace `imageNamed:` by `imageWithContentOfFile:` or `initWithContentOfFile:` ?

The memory management is different (no system cache):
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/initWithContentsOfFile:

> **Discussion**
>
> This method loads the image data into memory and marks it as purgeable. If the data is purged and needs to be reloaded, the image object loads that data again from the specified path.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/rickytan/RTImageAssets

install above plugin to xcode and go to file -> imageAssets ->Generate Missing assets.i will generate all missing images.

[image]

Comment: perfect plugin to generate missing assets.thanks you @Janak LN

Comment: Since I'm using PDF files for assets there are no missing assets. There is one asset per image and on build all the required images sizes are created by the image asset.

Answer (score 0):

The only possibility I can see here, is that a specific device might not have the proper file. For example, if the device has Retina display and there is no @2x image in the image asset then it will be returned as nil etc.

My suggestion is to make sure all required sizes are actually exist inside the image asset + make sure to use *asset group name* for the imageNamed: parameter.

Also, are you testing it over various simulators or real devices?

Comment: I've tested it on the device on which is crashed. It doesn't always crash. I can't even reproduce it on the device, it just sometimes crashes.

Answer (score 0):

It may possible that you are using hight resolution image & check on iPhone 4/4s or vise-a-versa.
Add all the sizes of images in image assets & then check for the image, whether it returns nil or not.
No need to mention @2x,@3x if we are using image assets,it will automatically take appropriate size from image assets.

Comment: I'm using a single vector, so no `@2x` or `@3x`. Also it seems to happen on iPhone 6 as well.

Comment: If you are using images seperately, Not using image.xcassets then you can access image directly from <imageName.png>

Comment: I know this, bud I'm sure assest catelog with vector images! Thus there are nog .png files and no size with `@2x` or `@3x`.